# First value duplicate in array while using array_search function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

I am trying to remove duplicates from two dimensional array based on client ID. The script removes all duplicates EXCEPT the first value, first client.

I have tried few more ways of comparing result from array_search to different values, trying to use !== and === with no promising result.

Inserting non numeric value as first in the array, makes everything deduplicate flawlessly.

Here is the code:

```
// Build client list
$ClientList = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach ($ClientTrans as $order => $value) {
    $ClientId = $ClientTrans[$order]['customer_id'];
if (array_search($ClientId, array_column($ClientList, 0)) == FALSE && is_numeric($ClientId)) {
        $ClientList[$counter][] = $ClientId;
        $counter += 1;
    }
}
```

The final result is a client and a sum up value from two dimensional array. Everything works as it should except for the first client, that appears multiple times in the new build client list without duplicates.

Here's the Input Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245901 
            [points] => 299 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245907 
            [points] => 3847 
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
            [customer_id] => 50245908 
            [points] => 159 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245910 
            [points] => 3175 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245914 
            [points] => 641 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245916 
            [points] => 449 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245921 
            [points] => 551 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245927 
            [points] => 0 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245928 
            [points] => 602 
    ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245929 
            [points] => 495 
    )
    [10] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245931 
            [points] => 539 
    ) 
    [11] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245941 
            [points] => 0 
    ) 
    [12] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245901 
            [points] => 124 
    ) 
    [13] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245901 
            [points] => 512 
    )
)
```

And desired output - customer id 50245901 is not appearing multiple times:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245901 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [customer_id] => 50245907 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245908 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245910 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245914 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245916 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245921 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245927 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245928 
    ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245929 
    ) 
    [10] => Array ( 
        [customer_id] => 50245931 
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you show what your input array looks like, and what the expected result of that should be?

Comment: Please post input array values as well as what expected outcome you want finally

Comment: Hello. I have added the array values example and the outcome to the question.

Comment: I see two interesting but different ways to resolve it, but does anyone additionaly know why does this happen, that the value for the first array keeps adding itself? Is it because False == 0 and the place in array for it is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simplify your `foreach()` like below:-

```
$ClientList = array();

foreach ($ClientTrans as $order => $value) {
    $ClientList[$value['customer_id']]['customer_id'] = $value['customer_id'];
}
$ClientList = array_values($ClientList);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/f7Bfn

Comment: Thank you kindly. This way works perfectly.  Though I am still confused about the issue that  was caused by array search in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write code,

```
$arr = array_values(array_unique(array_column($arr, 'customer_id')));
$temp = [];
array_walk($arr, function(&$item,$key) use(&$temp){
    $temp[]['customer_id'] = $item; 
});
print_r($temp);
```

[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) — Return all the values of an array
[array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) — Removes duplicate values from an array
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array
[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99d4032263ed38331fd2fc674c16b0c6f9526c56).